# Create an alert in JavaScript with html input inside

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, input, alert

Is it possible to create an alert with an html input?

```
<input name="avatar" id="file" type="file" value="">
```

I would like to pop up an alert on a button click who asks for a file.

Is it possible? What is the best way to do it?

I'm working on jquery-mobile.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sounds like you want a lightbox-type popup.

Comment: If you mean the native `alert(...)` then the answer is no.

Comment: http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to use a plugin, like jQuery.bPopup, according to your existent requirements.

http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

```
    $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        onOpen: function() {
            content.html("<your HTML code>");
        },
        onClose: function() {
            content.empty();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, since that the `alert` function is handled by the browser, you **can't** control or put Elements inside an alert.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible. You can not show file input controls inside an alert box. You will need to use a third party plugin that creates a custom dialog box which contains your form.

Answer (score 0):

Not with a file input.

But I think you can use the prompt() function to display a message with a textbox inside that.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt